# c++ subscript operator to underling class vector

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

So i'm trying to create a vec class that I can do vec math on at a later point.

Was working great until I began Implementing actual procedures on it.

Class vecn:

```
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class vecn
{
public:
    vecn() {    }
    template <typename... Args>
    vecn(Args&&... args)
    {
        addtovector(args...);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vecn<T>& obj)
    {
        os << "{";
        for (auto it = obj.contents.begin(); it < obj.contents.end(); it++) {
            os << *it;
            if (it != obj.contents.end() -1)
            {
                os << ",";
            }
        }
        os << "}";
        return os;
    }

    template<typename T>
    vecn<T>& operator=(const vecn<T>& v) {
        contents = v.contents;
        return *this;
    }

    unsigned int size() const
    {
        return contents.size();
    }

    vecn<T> operator+(const vecn<T>& v1) {
        vecn<T> v2();
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size();i++)
        {
            v2[i] = v1[i] + this->contents[i];
        }
        return v2;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t Index)
    { 
        if (Index > contents.size() -1)
        {
            contents.resize(Index + 1);
        }
        return contents.at(Index);
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t Index) const
    {
        return contents.at(Index);
    }

private:
    template <typename... Args>
    void addtovector(T& first, Args&&... args)
    {
        addtovector(first);
        addtovector(args...);
    }

    void addtovector(T& item)
    {
        contents.push_back(item);
    }
    std::vector<T> contents;
};
```

Now i'm having a problem with acceing the underling vector using the subscript operator, no matter how I design it, it never quite works. Usually resulting in a

```
Error   C2109   subscript requires array or pointer type
```

From Googling the error, I'm supposed to return a pointer to the array with the subscript. which I do.

Is there something i'm missing?

main:

```
vecn<int> v(1,2);
vecn<int> b(3, 4, 5);
std::cout << v + b;
```

Expected output:

```
{4,6,5}
```

Comment: at first you shoudn't use `template<typename T>
` keyword in `operator=`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GCC told me exactly what's wrong:

```
error: declaration of template parameter ‘T’ shadows template parameter
```

(for your assignment operator)

Then:

```
warning: pointer to a function used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         v2[i] = v1[i] + this->contents[i];
```

(you've declared `v2` as a function returning `vecn<T>`, remove the parentheses)

Lastly, fix your `operator+`, because it will try to access elements of an empty `v2` vector and access out of range of the smaller of `v1` and `this->contents` if their sizes are not equal.

---

It seems to me that you have wrote a lot of unnecessary code for such a simple thing. You don't need `addtovector`, just expand the parameter pack like:

```
contents{std::forward<Args>(args)...}
```

in the member initializer list. You don't need to define `operator=` at all, leave it up to the compiler. And try to [implement `operator+` in terms of `operator+=`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/what-are-the-basic-rules-and-idioms-for-operator-overloading/4421719#4421719).

Comment: Wonder why visual studios issent giving me these errors.

Answer (score 0):

Despite all other things you have one rather creepy thing in your code

```
if (Index > contents.size() -1)
```

You should never ever replace the correct choice of the boolean operator by arithmetic operations! std::vector<>.size() returns size_t (unsigned long on most systems), only your selfmade size() returns int, which it shouldn´t since there is no meaning in negative sizes.

Now 0 - 1 doesn´t yield a negative with 0 being size_t but something huuuge: 18446744073709551615 (0xffffffffffffffff).

So with size()=0

```
if (Index > contents.size() -1)
```

Will never ever be true and your vec will not grow, as you wanted, on access to vec[0]. Simply use

```
if (Index >= contents.size())
```

Which is exactly what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Likely your problem was that you used `vecn<T> v2();` instead of `vecn<T> v2;`, but there are another bad things in your solution. Here is some refactor:

```
template <typename T>
class vecn {
public:
    vecn() {}
    template <typename... Args>
    vecn(Args&&... args)
    {
        addToVector(args...);
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const vecn<T>& obj)
    {
        os << "{";
        for (auto it = obj.contents.begin(); it < obj.contents.end(); it++) {
            os << *it;
            if (it != obj.contents.end() - 1)
                os << ",";
        }
        os << "}";
        return os;
    }

    // you don't need this
    // template<typename T>

    // also whole method is unnecessary
    //    vecn<T>& operator=(const vecn<T>& v)
    //    {
    //        contents = v.contents;
    //        return *this;
    //    }

    // use size_t
    /*unsigned int*/ size_t size() const
    {
        return contents.size();
    }

    vecn<T> operator+(const vecn<T>& other) const
    {
        vecn<T> result;
        size_t resultSize = std::max(other.size(), size());
        result.contents.reserve(resultSize);

        for (size_t i = 0; i < resultSize; ++i) {
            T value = {};
            if (i < other.size())
                value += other.contents[i];
            if (i < size())
                value += contents[i];

            result.contents.push_back(value);
        }

        return result;
    }

    T& operator[](size_t index)
    {
        return contents.at(index);
    }

    const T& operator[](size_t index) const
    {
        return contents.at(index);
    }

private:
    template <typename... Args>
    void addToVector(T& first, Args&&... args)
    {
        addToVector(first);
        addToVector(args...);
    }

    void addToVector(T& item)
    {
        contents.push_back(item);
    }
    std::vector<T> contents;
};
```